# Validate user input with whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, validation, input-mask

How to in real-time format user input? For example, the user puts `A9364470240ZGS001` to the input field, and using JavaScript format it in the input field in real-time to be like: `A 936 447 02 40 ZGS 001`?

```
<div class="childDumpFile">
     <label for="ds">Dataset</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ds" name="ds" value="{{Request::get('ds') ?? ''}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you actually mean format the input value as users types?

Comment: Yes, user types ```A9364470240ZGS001``` and I need that in real-time string will be formated to ```A 936 447 02 40 ZGS 001```.

Comment: Is there any logical background in your fomat? and I wonder are users have to write this value one by one or they can paste it? I prepared a code to provide real time format but users have to write the value one by one.

Comment: No, I didn't write any logic on formating. But if it's hard to implement this logic in real-time, it can be without real-time. I just need to format this string ```A9364470240ZGS001```, to ```A 936 447 02 40 ZGS 001```.

Comment: You can check it from [here](https://gist.github.com/AbdulkerimFettahoglu/5839181370b4140e2bd40a9017d0a0dc) . But as I sad before users have to write one by one the characters.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out!

Comment: I upvoted your question. I am wondering what is the true answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the true answer. These expectations are naming as "input-mask" and if you'd like to use. You have to use 3. party libraries. Some of them listing in following sites:

[Libraries 1](https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/)
[Libraries 2](https://bashooka.com/coding/javascript-input-mask-libraries/)

I chose `Cleave.js` for your question. This is the demo:

```
<script src="https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/dist/cleave.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/dist/cleave-phone.i18n.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadFunction() {
        // custom
        var cleaveCustom = new Cleave('.input-custom', {
            blocks: [1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3],
            delimiter: ' ',
        });
    }
</script>

<body onload="loadFunction()">
    A 936 447 02 40 ZGS 001
    <div class="container">
        <input class="input-custom" placeholder="Custom delimiter & blocks" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose users have to write the characters one by one. This will work.

```
<body>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ds" name="ds" onkeypress="keyPress()" maxlength="23">
</body>
<script>
    function keyPress() {
        var field = document.getElementById("ds");
        var text = field.value;
        if(text.length == 1 || text.length == 5 
        || text.length == 9 || text.length == 12
        || text.length == 15 || text.length == 19 ) {
            var newText = text + " ";
            field.value = newText;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example.

```
<div class="childDumpFile">
     <label for="ds">Dataset</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ds" name="ds">
</div>

<div class="test_ds"></div>
```

JS with jquery.

```
$("#ds").change(function(){
    var ds_value = $("#ds").val();

var temp = ds_value;
temp = temp.substring(0,1) + " " + temp.substring(1, 4) + " " + temp.substring(4, 7) + " " + temp.substring(7, 9) + " " + temp.substring(9, 11) + " " + temp.substring(11, 14) + " " + temp.substring(14, 17);

  $("#ds").val(temp);
  $(".test_ds").html(temp);
});
```

Here is a demo - 
https://jsfiddle.net/Kistlak/7bkdtev8

Comment: I checked your demo. I have to leave the box to start validation. He is asking for real time. Your answer is working like `onChange()` event

Answer (score -1):

First, you need add onchange="getTimeNow()" oninput="getTimeNow()" in to input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ds" name="ds" value="{{Request::get('ds') ?? ''}}" onchange="getTimeNow()" oninput="getTimeNow()">
```

Finally, you get event input text

```
<script>function getTimeNow(){console.log(new Date())}</script>
```

Comment: I need to format string in real-time. It's not what I have asked for.